# How to display an HTML asset file?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an `.html` file in my `assets` directory.

How can I display / render it in Flutter?

Answer (score 7):

The package from the **Flutter Team** was released yesterday:

[webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter)

How to load local asset:

Add the file to the project and update your pubspec:

```
//...
assets:
    //...
    - assets/yourFile.html
    //...
```

---

In your widget:

```
child: FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: LocalLoader().loadLocal(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      //                                return Text("${snapshot.data}");
      return WebView(
        initialUrl: new Uri.dataFromString(snapshot.data,
                mimeType: 'text/html')
            .toString(),
        // maybe you Uri.dataFromString(snapshot.data, mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")).toString()
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

Loading the text from the file:

```
class LocalLoader {
  Future<String> loadLocal() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/yourFile.html');
  }
}
```

Comment: Got error "Invalid argument(s): String contains invalid characters.". I had to add parameter "encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")" to Uri.dataFromString because method otherwise uses ASCII encoding. Otherwise: wonderful solution!

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) this should work with local files too.

It works both on Android and iOS

**Dart**

```
var flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

flutterWebviewPlugin.launch("https://flutter.io");
await flutterWebviewPlugin.onDestroy.first;
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<activity android:name="com.flutter_webview_plugin.WebviewActivity"
                  android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the apk package. I found the reason: `path is wrong`

For Android:

```
"assets/test.html" == "file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/test.html"
```

so, just like this:

```
WebView(
    initialUrl: "file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/test.html",
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
)
```

you can load `assets/test.html`.

Comment: for iOS ? How to get file path? **'file:///android_asset/flutter_assets' do not work for iOS**

Comment: @jazzbpn Do you find any way to do so in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [flutter_inappbrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser) plugin (**EDIT**: it has been renamed to [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)), that is a Flutter Plugin that allows you to add an **inline webview** integrated with the widget tree or open an **in-app browser** window!

You can use the [InAppWebView](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inappwebview-class) widget class or the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inappbrowser-class) class and use its webview controller.

In your case, you can use the `InAppWebViewController.loadFile` method.

To be able to load your local files (html, js, css, etc.), you need to add them in the assets section of the pubspec.yaml file, otherwise they cannot be found!

Example of a `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
...

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/index.html
    - assets/css/
    - assets/images/

...
```

Then, call the method in your business logic:

```
inAppWebViewController.loadFile("assets/index.html");
```

or

```
InAppWebView(
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
    var uri = "assets/index.html"
    controller.loadFile(assetFilePath: uri);
  },
),
```

Comment: pity that InAppWebViewController.takeScreenshot is not working on ios:(

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to render simple HTML tags (p,img,a,h1,etc.) you could try this [flutter_html plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html)

It's not mature enough for production yet IMHO but worth considering / contributing.