# How to use simple local HTML file in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm developing a flutter app and the only thing left for me is the content, and when I got the content I got it as HTML file that includes only text,
I looked everywhere but I couldn't find a way to do so.

So what I'm trying to achieve is:

- Include HTML files in my project.
- Find a way to display the content in a widget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an HTML asset file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428388/how-to-display-an-html-asset-file)

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_view

Comment: where can i put the html files so that the project will recognise them as assets and i can access to them as .../stories/chapter001.html?
and i can open them as 
lutterWebviewPlugin.launch(".../stories/chapter001.html");

Comment: "can open them as lutterWebviewPlugin.launch(".../stories/chapter001.html");" There is no way to do that. Reading assets requires an AssetReader. You could implement an HTTP server into your app where you allow webview to fetch the data from (which then loads it using AssetReader) and serves it. See also https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/23 and especially the Medium link in the 2nd comment.