# Dart: Load an html file into a Flutter Webview

Tags: javascript, android, dart, flutter

Sthg makes me crazy, I try to write an html file on the disk using the path_provider plugin with the dart:io library.

Here is what I tried (**OKAY**):

```
Future<File> writeFile() async {
   final file = await _localFile;
   return file.writeAsString('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>test_design</title> ...');
 }
```

then the file is loaded in a webview: **OKAY**

But if I try with a longer html file, it doesn't work anymore, eg :

```
return file.writeAsString(' html file containing js ');
```

Any idea?

or how to load an html file (the file is not static) in a Flutter webview ?

---

I use **flutter_webview_plugin.dart**

(https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

webview code :

```
         writeFile().then((file){
            readFile().then((r){
               _localPath.then((path){
                    var uri='file:///'+path+'/index.html';

                    flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(uri,
                        rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
                          0.0,
                          400.0,
                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          200.0,
                        ),
                      );
```

Comment: Show us the webview code and webview plugin url.

Comment: @Spectarion I updated the question with what you asked

Comment: try this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428388/how-to-display-an-html-asset-file/54364651#54364651

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this is the approach for this:

This is an example approach, I will be building a Flutter app that can read file and write data to file for later use.

It is an app that could write the String to **text.txt** file. Everytime the app is launched it will display the contents of **text.txt**.

I need a place to write data on disk and read it again when the app loads. So I used [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install) plugin to access Documents directory (on iOS, this corresponds to `NSDocumentDirectory`, on Android, this is the `AppData` directory).

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}
```

Create a reference to the File full location (in our case, the text.txt file), we use [File](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html) class from the [dart:io](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) library.

```
Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/text.txt');
}
```

Need to write a string to a file using File `writeAsString()` method. It returns a `Future<File>` that completes with this File object once the entire operation has completed.

By default, `writeAsString()` creates the file and truncates the file if it already exists.

To append data to existing file, pass `FileMode.append` mode as second parameter.

```
Future<File> writeFile(String text) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  return file.writeAsString('$text\r\n', mode: FileMode.append);
}
```

Use File `readAsString()` method to read the entire contents as a string. It returns a `Future<String>` that completes with the string once contents has been read.

```
Future<String> readFile() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
 
    String content = await file.readAsString();
    return content;
  } catch (e) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Here is the complete sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Read/Write Files',
      home: MyApp(storage: TextStorage()),
    ),
  );
}

class TextStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/text.txt');
  }

  Future<String> readFile() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      String content = await file.readAsString();
      return content;
    } catch (e) {
      return '';
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeFile(String text) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsString('$text\r\n', mode: FileMode.append);
  }

  Future<File> cleanFile() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsString('');
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextStorage storage;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController _textField = new TextEditingController();

  String _content = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readFile().then((String text) {
      setState(() {
        _content = text;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> _writeStringToTextFile(String text) async {
    setState(() {
      _content += text + '\r\n';
    });

    return widget.storage.writeFile(text);
  }

  Future<File> _clearContentsInTextFile() async {
    setState(() {
      _content = '';
    });

    return widget.storage.cleanFile();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Read/Write File Example'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _textField,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Write to File'),
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_textField.text.isNotEmpty) {
                    _writeStringToTextFile(_textField.text);
                    _textField.clear();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Clear Contents',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.grey,
                onPressed: () {
                  _clearContentsInTextFile();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(
                  '$_content',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how it looks when run:

[image]

You can play around depending on your requirement.

Also for your other question on how to load an html file in Flutter webview, here is my approach:

You can actually make it work using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.

Create an assets folder in the root directory of your Flutter application, then  put your .html file in the assets folder.

You should add your .html file to under `assets` in your *`pubspec.yaml`* file.

*`pubspec.yaml`*

```
  assets:
    - assets/SampleHtml.html
```

Here is a sample implementation to load an html from a local file:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> localLoader() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/SampleHtml.html');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: localLoader(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return WebView(
              initialUrl:
                  new Uri.dataFromString(snapshot.data, mimeType: 'text/html')
                      .toString(),
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}
```

*`SampleHtml.html`*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample HTML</title>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Flutter Webview</h1>
        <p>A Flutter plugin that provides a WebView widget.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Can you tell me what controls the size of the characters displayed? I tried your html file, but the text is very tiny. My device is a Pixel 5 running Chromium. My concern is if it is a readable size for you, is it the choice of browser?

Comment: Regarding the small size, I found a solution at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752837/webview-flutter-font-size-is-too-small-in-ios